# Angular : ng-message validation on submit click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ng-messages

I am working on application where I've one form and It should show validation error message for input fields on wrong input.

**My form will look like this -**

[image]

**It should show error message if -**

1. Input field modified with wrong input
2. Submit button clicked without modification in required input field.

**It should show error message as below -**

[image]

To achieve this I am using ng-message directive. It wil help me to show error message on $dirty of input field. But for Submit button I could not find correct way. Currently I am using a flag which will be modified on submit click. But I am interested in some better approach. Is there predefined method available to achieve this ?

Here is the complete example which I tried, and here is [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BZKENyIxaSYKLi8BI0nT?p=preview) for the same.

```
 <!doctype html>

 <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
     <script>
         var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);
         app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

             $scope.submitForm = function() {
                 $scope.submitted = true;
                 if (myForm.$valid) {
                     alert('Form submitted with passed validation');
                 }
             };

         });
     </script>
 </head>

 <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm()">
         <label>
             Enter your name:
             <input type="text" name="myName" ng-model="name" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required />
         </label>

         <div ng-if="submitted || myForm.myName.$dirty" ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:red" role="alert">
             <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
             <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
             <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
         </div>
         <br>
         <br>
         <label>
             Enter your phone number:
             <input type="number" name="myPhone" ng-model="phone" ng-maxlength="20" required />
         </label>

         <div ng-if="submitted || myForm.myPhone.$dirty" ng-messages="myForm.myPhone.$error" style="color:red" role="alert">
             <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
             <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
         </div>
         <br>
         <br>

         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `myForm.$submitted`

Comment: Why don't you use angular 2 form validation techniques. if you are using angualr 2. https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-form-validation

Comment: @Harshakj89, he is using `angular1.5.0` not angular2.

Comment: try - $scope.myForm.$setSubmitted(true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`$submitted`** for the form,

**`Syntax: formname.$submitted`**

**$submitted :** True if user has submitted the form even if its invalid.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
     
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);
         app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

             $scope.submitForm = function() {
                 
                 if (myForm.$valid) {
                     alert('Form submitted with passed validation');
                 }
             };

         });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm()">
         <label>
             Enter your name:
             <input type="text" name="myName" ng-model="name" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required />
         </label>

         <div ng-if="myForm.$submitted || myForm.myName.$dirty" ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:red" role="alert">
             <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
             <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
             <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
         </div>
         <br>
         <br>
         <label>
             Enter your phone number:
             <input type="number" name="myPhone" ng-model="phone" ng-maxlength="20" required />
         </label>

         <div ng-if="myForm.$submitted || myForm.myPhone.$dirty" ng-messages="myForm.myPhone.$error" style="color:red" role="alert">
             <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
             <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
         </div>
         <br>
         <br>

         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
 </body>

</html>
```

**Please run this snippet and check.**

[Here is the reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

[The changed plunker link of yours](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lzeow2sUmjkr0MbMtRDr?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Update Plunker [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/HO7bUmF4w8GUoV7zUL3N?p=preview)

```
You could go with disabling submit button till your form isn't correct one
```